# What's the intended use of `servlet-context.xml`, `root-context.xml` and `web.xml`?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I a new to Java Spring MVC web development. I am kind of confused by the 3 config files below. They are auto created by the STS webmvc project template.

- What's the intended use of them?
- Why do we need 3 config files rather than a single one?
- Is there any special reason for their different locations?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`root-context.xml` is the Spring **Root** Application Context Configuration. It's optional. It's for configuring your **non-web** beans. You need it for Spring Security or OpenEntityManagerInView Filter though. It would be better to place it in `meta-inf/spring`.

`servlet-context.xml` is the Spring **Web** Application Context Configuration. It's for configuring your Spring beans in a web application. If you use `root-context.xml`, you should put your non-web beans in `root-context.xml`, and web beans in `servlet-context.xml`.

`web.xml` is for configuring your **servlet container**, such as Tomcat. You need this one too. It's for configuring servlet filters and the servlet. `web.xml` is loaded first, then optionally loads your root context, then loads your web context.

You can avoid using xml by using JavaConfig.

Comment: Could you also mention about the corresponding javaConfig equivalent for all three of the xml? It would be helpful for newbies like us.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file name "javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer" (without quotes)  the file content will be fully qualified name of the class implementing this interface, put the file here /META-INF/services

You may implement ServletContainerInitializer and override the method like this

```
public class CourtServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(CourtConfiguration.class);

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = ctx.addServlet("court", dispatcherServlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

After this you do not need web.xml

Do remember if you are using maven to build your application mention this in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

Before that you have to write a configuration class using @Configuration and @Bean annotations

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.practice.learnspringmvc.*")

public class CourtConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

This configuration class replaces your `<bean></bean>` initializers from servlet-context.xml