# How spring framework loads context.xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LaT5.png)

This is the default project created by STS.

and there are xml code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  
  <annotation-driven /> 



  <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 



  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </beans:bean>
  
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.hee.heechart" /> - 
 
</beans:beans>
```

I don't understand.. how springframework loads context.xml file

The servlet-context.xml file and root-context.xml file works well, but I don't know the springframework structure of loading the root-context.xml file and servlet-context.xml file.

Is it possible to load the appServlet folder in WEB-INF folder because it is located in the classpath?

Comment: Note that this style is outdated; Spring Boot is the modern style. However, in any Spring application there has to be an _entry point_, and in an XML Web application it's the `servlet-context.xml`, which you will see has an instruction that tells the container to load a certain Spring class (usually `DispatcherServlet`) and provide it with a certain context definition.

Comment: check the SO answer for similar question as yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893886/whats-the-intended-use-of-servlet-context-xml-root-context-xml-and-web-xm